# Reverse engineering base64 variation

Tags: reverse-engineering, base64

I'm dealing with a strange base64 variation. I need to write decoder for it but I've stuck with reverse engineering. It differs not so much from original base64. It looks like there's something with bit padding or smth.

Here are some known encoded strings:

- YQ== - a
- YQA= - aa
- YQBh - aaa
- YQBhAA== - aaaa
- YQBhAGE= - aaaaa
- YQBhAGEA - aaaaaa
- YQBhAGEAYQ== - aaaaaaa
- YQBhAGEAYQA= - aaaaaaaa
- YQBhAGEAYQBh - aaaaaaaaa

Comment: how does a blank string encodes?

Comment: Blank strings aren't encoded at all like does original base64 encoder.

Comment: Please post more examples. I suppose the "bit endianness" is changed.

Comment: One more example. Actual strings are:
YQBhAGEAYQ== - aaaaaaa
YQBhAGEAYQA= - aaaaaaaa
YQBhAGEAYQBh - aaaaaaaaa.

Regular base64 decoder returns "aaaa" in all three cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of sounding stupid, my bet would be that the encoding above is a buggy implementation that is mixing chars and wchar_ts together.

Using "regular" base64, the string 'YQA=' decodes to 'a\x00' and 
the 'YQBhAGEAYQA=' decodes to 'a\x00a\x00a\x00a\x00'.

Any chance you could supply a few more examples so we can cancel this theory?

Comment: The problem wasn't an algorithm but data.